# Show that this set is convex

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ be convex with nonempty interior, i.e. $K^{\circ}\neq \emptyset$. I want to show that the set

$$A:=\{x\in \bar{K}:d(x,\mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}) \geq 1/n\}$$

is convex, where $n\geq 1$, $\bar{K}$ denotes the closure of $K$, and $d(x,\mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}):=\inf\{||x-y||: y\in\mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}\}.$ Note that $A=\bar{K}$ if $K=\mathbb{R}^p$.

Using continuity of the distance function I was able to show that $A$ is closed (using the sequence criterion), but I don't know how to proceed next.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you come across the term 'contraction' of a convex set?

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry I am not familiar with this term.

Comment: I am thinking about keywords to better describe the question. It's also about subtracting a margin from a convex set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in A$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and suppose $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \not\in A$. Then for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}$ we have $d(x,a)\geq 1/n$ and $d(y,a) \geq 1/n$, but there exists a $b \in\mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}$ such that $d(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y,b)<1/n$. I will show that this leads to a contradiction.

Note that $\{a : d(x,a)< 1/n\} \subset K^{\circ}$ and $\{a : d(y,a)< 1/n\} \subset K^{\circ}$. Since $d(x, x+b-\lambda x - (1-\lambda)y)<1/n$, $x+b-\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in K^{\circ}$ . Similarly, $y+b-\lambda x - (1-\lambda)y \in K^{\circ}$. Since $K^\circ$ is convex,
$$\lambda\left[x+b-\lambda x - (1-\lambda)y\right] + (1-\lambda)\left[y+b-\lambda x - (1-\lambda)y\right]=b\in K^\circ,$$
which is a contradiction with $b \in\mathbb{R}^p\setminus K^{\circ}$.

Comment: Could you expand on why $\{a : d(x,a)< 1/n\} \subset K^{\circ}$?

Comment: @Alphie that's because elements from that set are in $\mathbb{R}^p$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^p \setminus K^{\circ}$

Comment: Oh right! Thank you so much for this very nice proof!

Comment: Is guess the geometric idea is that if a point on the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ was outside of $A$, then this point would be close to a point outside of $K^{\circ}$. So close that this outside point would lie on a line segment connecting two points in balls centered at $x$ and $y$ which are contained in $K^{\circ}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Alphie that's correct

Comment: The assumption of nonempty interior was not needed I believe right? In this case we would have $A=\emptyset$ which is vacuoulsy convex.

Comment: @Alphie right, you may even be able to define $A$ based on the *relative* interior of $K$